# How to Highcharts max height based on width of bars in chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Looking at the best way to set a chart height property using highcharts bar chart.

Currently I have set chart height to be equal to the number of X axis categories, but not less than 400 using:

```
this.resultsChartOptions.chart.height = ((categories.length * 50) > 400 ? categories.length * 50 : 400);
```

This however means there are overlaps between bars especially on larger charts (as the legend and other chart stuff takes up room I have not accounted for).

I have set a default pointWidth to 50 and that is the widest bar - ideally every category would just be 50 wide and the chart would auto expand.

Anyone any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `load` event you can calculate and set the required height taking into account all elements of the chart:

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 400,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var categories = this.xAxis[0].tickPositions,
                plotHeight = categories.length * 50,
                chartHeight = plotHeight + (this.chartHeight - this.plotHeight);

            if (chartHeight > this.chartHeight) {
                this.setSize(null, chartHeight, false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hkuLfogj/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize

Comment: This is just giving me more errors? Though I am using the vue wrapper for highcharts would this make a difference?

Comment: Hi Adam Waring, This solution should not cause any problems. Alternatively, if the others elements of your chart have a fixed height, you can calculate the needed space before creating the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8epc6jL1/

Comment: I cannot calculate the chart size before rendering because the students (xAxis) are loaded after the chart is - main error seems to bbe that it doesn't recognise chartheigh and plotheight

Comment: Hi Adam Waring, Please provide me with minimal live example of this problem. Without the code I can not help you.